# Remove everything between ? and # in string

Tags: javascript

Ive got this string:

```
http://localhost:8080/Test/index.html?node=station:|slot:/gooberVille/Neverland/Hola#/overview/standard
```

And I want to remove everything between the first instance  of '?' and the first instance of '#' following '?'.

I thought about slice() for awhile, but I dont think that is gonna cut it. So punny.

Thanks!

Comment: google regex replace close question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using regular expressions:

```
var s = 'http://localhost:8080/Test/index.html?node=station:|slot:/gooberVille/Neverland/Hola#/overview/standard';
s = s.replace(/\?.*?#/, '');
```

`?` is a special character in regular expressions, so to match a literal `?` you escape it with a backslash.  `.` matches any character, `.*` matches any number of any character (as many as possible), and `.*?` matches any number of any character (as few as possible).  So `/\?.*?#/` will match starting from the first `?`, then as few characters as possible until a `#` is found.  By replacing a match of this regex with an empty string you get the result you want.

If you want to keep the `#` in the string, just change it to `s.replace(/\?.*?#/, '#')`.

Comment: So change '' to '#' in replace

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions would be your best bet

```
string = string.replace(/\?.*?#/, '');
```